# Multiple Linear Regression Best Model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, model

I currently have a dataset and am trying to find the best multiple-linear regression model that answers my research question. The given dataset has 6 independent variables which I am going to be using for my predictors. However, I am having a little bit of trouble on whether or not my approach would be correct:

I plan to create a residual plot of my fitted model with all the predictors to see if there are any violations. If there are violations (normality, homoscedasticity), I would apply some sort of transformation whether it be log, box-cox, etc. However, my problem arises, am I able to apply a transformation for one specific predictor and then re-fit to see if there are still violations or am I forced to apply a transformation for all predictors. What I mean by this is suppose the first model I fit is $y = b_1x_1 + b_2x_2+\cdots+ b_5x_5$. Could I apply a transformation such that it becomes $y = b_1\log(x_1) + b_2x_2+\cdots+b_5x_5$ and then see if there are any violations, or does it have to be $y = b_1\log(x_1) + b_2\log(x_2)+\cdots+ b_5\log(x_5)$

My other question is concerning residual plots. When creating the residual plots, it should be the residuals of my fitted model right? In other words, I should not create residual plots of each individual predictor with the outcome variable (in a SLR), but rather it should be the residuals of this model $y = b_1x_1 + b_2x_2+\cdots+ b_5x_5. $

Comment: For your first question, you can transform any or all of your variables.  The transformation can differ from on to another.  You should first consider if there theoretical justification for the model before randomly applying variable transformations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply however I still am a little confused. I was thinking at looking at residual plots to see if it justifies a transformation. However, in this case, would I be looking at residual plots for my fitted multi linear model otherwise I am not sure how else to see if it violates the assumptions of linear regression.

Comment: The residual plots are for the fitted model.  If the residuals violates an assumption then maybe a transformation will help, this is where some expertise is required on how to choose the right variable and transformation.